# (JavaScript) Appending to an object is not appending

Tags: javascript

I am trying to append something to an object, but instead I get a new object and I can't figure this out.

I have a list of 700 items, which I am using a simple for loop to iterate over, I want to append a date (which is one of the pieces of data) to an object.

So:

```js
let dailyTots = {}

for (let x = 0; x < allData.length; x++) {

    let theDate = allData[x].date

    dailyTots = {
        ...dailyTots,
        date: theDate,                       
    }
    console.log(dailyTots)                   
}
```

what I expected to see when I console logged this was the object gradually getting larger (eg `{ date: '2019-01-01' }`, then `{ date: '2019-01-01', date: '2019-01-02' }`
insead I get a single
`{ date: '2019-01-01' }`

I can't see what I've done wrong

Comment: What you want is impossible. A property can not exist more than once in an object. You probably want an array of objects.

Comment: An object cannot have multiple properties with the same name

Comment: `const dailyTots  = allData.map(function (x) { return {date: x.date}; });` or `const dailyTots  = allData.map(({date}) => ({ date }));`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll probably want to do something like this:

```
const dailyTots = [];

for (let x = 0; x < allData.length; x++) {

    const theDate = allData[x].date

    dailyTots.push({date: theDate});
    console.log(dailyTots)                   
}
```